# How can we decode the Request URL from JSONP. using PHP

Tags: php, json, jsonp

Hello I would like to decode the Request URL which we are getting from JavaScript using JSONP.

```
http://localhost/kendo-prac/data/update.php?callback=jQuery17108347283969633281_1331377855406&models=%5B%7B%22ID%22%3A%2213%22%2C%22Title%22%3A%22RODDER%22%7D%5D&_=1331377869224
```

How can we make it usable in $_GET[]  PHP.

Thanks

ROD.

UPDATED

```
<?php
$link = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Unable To Connect To Database Server");
mysql_select_db("users") or die("Unable To Connect To Northwind");

     header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');





  $tmp = json_decode($_GET['models']);
  $id = $tmp->ID;
  $title = $tmp->Title;


    $rs = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ldr (ID, Title) VALUES (".$id.",".$title.")");



?>
```

Please look at the above codes.

Comment: show us what wrong with your request, it looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

It's still usable in $_GET even if it's encoded, here's how to decode it:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)
{
    $_GET[$key] = json_decode($value);
}
```

Comment: due to this we can get $_GET['Title'],$_GET['ID'] outside the loop ?

Comment: You can get the title and ID like this `$_GET['models']->Title`, `$_GET['models']->ID`

Comment: i m getting $_GET['models'] = [{"ID":"13","Title":"RODDER"}]. Actually i just want to make this seprately, like $ID = 13; and $Title = "RODDER" ;  . how can we do that ?

Comment: `$tmp = json_decode($_GET['models']); $ID = $tmp->ID; $title = $tmp->Title;`

Comment: how can we do that, we have not made any object here .

Comment: please look at the UPdated question

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want.